# SQLite .DB file contents shown in Visual Studio Form DataGridView component

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, database-connection

So I have a database file (name.db) on my desktop, as well as a project folder containing my program. I want to create a form to test my program, however I cant seem to get my contents from my database into the form, so I can't even test my code. I try to "connect a database" from the tools menu, but none of the options will allow me to connect my ".db" file.

Below are the images of what I'm trying to do, so you can get an idea.

[The Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtWnt.png)

[The menu of different database options, none of which work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vBqp.png)

[The code for the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Opm.png)

[Files on the Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEmpp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you never make any requests/queries to your database. Since your database could and most probably does contain mutliple tables you should run a corresponding sql query and then display the result. The following [link](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html) should give you a good starting point how to integrate sqlite with c++.